# Formula field is updating continious with current date time

Tags: formula

I am assigning current date time on formula field once the correction counter value is 0.6 but the date is updating again with latest time . I want that if correction counter value is updated to 0.6 at 4/12/2019 at 12:00 pm than the formula field should contain the date time  as 4/12/2019 at 12:00 pm  . But in my org it is updating continuously with current time.

Below is the formula -

```
IF( Correction_Counters__c = 0.6, NOW(), blank_date__c )
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how formula fields work. They are calculated on the fly every time they are queried from the database. Instead, create a custom field to store the value, then use a Workflow Rule or Process to calculate the value once when the record is created.